I can’t upload data correctly using json_query in ansible-playbook
I am new to writing Ansible playbooks and have hit a roadblock.
I have a list of data in several wrapped form in an API:

In each item there is a drop-down list environments with several more items:

And in each of these items there is the data name and publish_date:

In the end the construction is like this:
1. results
- 0
- 1
- 2
  2.environments
   - 0
   - 1
      - name: "123"
      - publish_date: "4 months ago"

I need to load all names older than a certain date as a list.
I tried to do this:
vars:
  begin_date: "{{ lookup('pipe', 'date -d \"3 months ago\" -I') }}" #determined the date I needed

tasks:
  - debug:
      msg: "{{begin_date}}"

  - name: Get all data #display the entire list of API
    uri:
      url: "127.0.0.1/api"
      user: "{{user}}"
      password: "{{pass}}"
      method: GET
      force_basic_auth: yes
      status_code: 200
      validate_certs: no
    register: data
    ignore_errors: yes
 
  - name: debug #search and display all data older than 3 months using json_query
      debug:
        job: "{{ data.json.results | json_query('environments[*]',<3 months)| map(attribute='name') | list }}"
      register: job

  - debug:
      msg: "env 3 month before{{job}}"

But when executing the playbook the output is empty:
TASK [debug] ****
ok: [mytest] => {
    "msg": "env 3 month before""

Please help me understand what I'm doing wrong and where I'm wrong.

Please take a minute to edit your question and correct the formatting. There is help available in the editor.

I suppose the SO editor either has some kind of a bug or at least some inconsistent UI/UX because the image formatting issues are always almost the same in different SO questions.

@talion.kel I can't reproduce your issue. It's unclear whether your results and environments are lists or dicts, the date command uses a wrong syntax, the begin_date value is not used in the affected code, in JMESPath (which works under the hood of json_query) the ordering operators >, >=, <, <= are only valid for numbers, and job is not a valid parameter for the debug module - so your code can't be executed. And I would't call myself a JMESPath pro but I doubt it can compare the human-readable dates like this.
